# pdf not generated by itext library from java application

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using i-text to generate a PDF file from a java program. As long as I run my program through NetBeans it works fine. The PDF gets generated and all the data is present in the file. But when I run it from the built JAR file, there is no PDF file generated. Do I need to change something in the manifest or give some special permissions?

Comment: Make sure you are linking all dependency jars correctly when packaging your application. Or rather let the IDE do it.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you included some error logs or something to work on. We cannot magically solve problems by telepathy.

Comment: Do you use Maven? If not, you should! It takes care of all the heavy lifting with libs.

Comment: If iText works in NetBeans, there isn't any problem with iText, but there's a problem with the way you deploy an application. Unfortunately, you're not sharing any information that is helpful to diagnose what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know what to add. I'm really new with all this. I'm running the generated jar file of application on another system So i don't know how to find an error log of this. Its a gui. Kindly tell me what should i share to help you understand this.